# Build From Jenkins is Failing

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, build

I have integrated jenkins with my Project of iOS. But when i build my project then the error comes which is

```
Create product structure /bin/mkdir -p            
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyProject-core/workspace/build/MyProject.app
error: File is a broken symbolic link:
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/MyProject-core/workspace/build/MyProject.app
```

Can any one tells me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you ever figured out the root cause for this? We just got it too with XCode 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. i had to delete whole project from jenkins server for this build and get it from source control again and build.Then it all worked.  I reckon something went wrong with permissions .